# Why is markdown R package required error in Shiny app?

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard

I am recently deploying my shiny app on Shinyapps.io. But I got the following error:

```
Warning: Error in loadNamespace: there is no package called ‘markdown’
```

I do use `rmarkdown` package, but I did not use `markdown` package in my shiny app. I don't understand why ‘markdown’ package is required.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to install package markdown

Comment: @manro, it works after installing markdown. I am curious to know why do I need to install this package.

Comment: I don't know, maybe these packages have ties between them.